# Appcelerator Titanium - how to back up database to cloud (Android)?

Tags: android, database, titanium, cloud, appcelerator

I am trying to back up a database to the Appcelerator Cloud Services, however, the database fails to save. I currently have the following code:

```
var dbPath = 'file:///data/data/' + Ti.App.getID() + '/databases/';
var dbFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(dbPath + 'myDb'); 

Cloud.Files.create({
    name: 'myDb',
    file: dbFile
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var file = e.files[0];
        alert('File successfully backed up!');
    } else {
        alert('File save error!');
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What does error message says when failed?

Comment: In the program, I get the "File save error!" alert.  I don't see any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your file isn't bigger than 25MB size for file.

There is event error and message property with additional information why file creation failed.

```
Cloud.Files.create({
    name: 'myDb',
    file: dbFile
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var file = e.files[0];
        alert('File successfully backed up!');
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

For more detailed information see [Appcelerator Cloud documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/Files-method-create).

Comment: I figured out the problem; I needed to create a user and log in.